# Iterating over every name in a nested hash in array

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
students = [
  {name: "Dr. Hannibal Lecter", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Darth Vader", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Nurse Ratched", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Michael Corleone", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Alex DeLarge", cohort: :november},
  {name: "The Wicked Witch of the West", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Terminator", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Freddy Krueger", cohort: :november},
  {name: "The Joker", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Joffrey Baratheon", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Norman Bates", cohort: :november}
]
```

I attempted to iterate over every student's name in a loop:

```
def print_loop(students)
  puts "Would you like to list the students? 'Y/N'"
  answer = gets.chomp
  while answer != "N" do
    i = students[-1]
    students.each do |student, value|
      puts student[:name]
      break if i
      if answer == "Y"
        exit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It only iterates and loops over the first name. How do I get it to iterate over every name? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's up with the `i` and `break if i`?

Comment: I want it to iterate over every name and stop at the last. That is why I assigned students[-1] to "i", so it would break when the last student is listed.

Comment: Those are some unfriendly folk. I don't think you need to use a loop here. Can you not just use `each` to iterate over the array?

Comment: I have been asked to use a while loop.

Comment: Yes, they are unfriendly! :)

Comment: I have been asked to print out all the students using a control flow method.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. To iterate over each student just iterate--the `while` condition you have so far is pointless since you don't change the value of `answer` in the loop.

Comment: this sounds a lot like homework... go a step back, explain what you exactly want to do, this will be pretty straight forward once we understand it. There is so much useless code there, that we can't (or don't want to) guess what it should do...

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use a while loop, you can use an incrementing counter and loop while the counter is less than the size of the array

```
i = 0 

while i < students.size
  puts students[i][:name]
  i += 1
end
```

Note that this is idiosyncratic in ruby and you would normally use an `#each` loop.

If you want to use the while loop to allow the user to request to continue after every name...

```
i = 0
puts "Would you like to list the students? 'Y/N'"
answer = gets.chomp
while answer == 'Y'
  puts students[i][:name]
  i += 1
  puts "keep going? 'Y/N'"
  answer = gets.chomp
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic Ruby way to do this is:

```
puts students.collect{ |student| student[:name]}
```

If you must use a while loop, you'll need a counter `i` as well.

```
i = 0
while i < students.size
  puts students[i][:name]
  i += 1
end
```

If you also need to prompt for the list, do it outside the loop. Here I'll also show it outside the method.

```
def print_loop(students)
  i = 0
  while i < students.size
    puts students[i][:name]
    i += 1
  end
end
puts "Would you like to list the students? 'Y/N'"
answer = gets.chomp.upcase
print_loop(students) if answer == 'Y'
```